# Select2: searching for results from remote data sources using AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2

I have this Select2 in my html page:

```
<input class="users form-control" type="hidden" />
```

In my js function I did this:

```
$(".users").select2({        
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    multiple:true,
    ajax: {
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                'q': term
            };
        },                  
        results: function (data) {
            return { results: data };
        },
        transport: function(queryParams) {
            var params = {'term':queryParams.data.q};
            console.log(params);
            service.getUsersByQuery(params,function (data) { 

                return data;
            });
        }
    }    
});
```

My service is :

```
this.getUsersByQuery= function (criteria,callback){

        $http({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: criteria
        }).success(function(data){          
                    callback(data);             
            }).error(function(err){
                console.error('Error: %s error: %O', 'failed.', err);
            });
    }
```

I have my results in `transport` but I am not able to obtain the result in `processResult`. What changes do I need to make to get this working?

I am using Select2 3.4.5.

Comment: Can you add an example of what is coming back in `data`?

Comment: I modified my question...

Comment: Are you using `ng-select2`? Or are you just using Select2 with AngularJS? And what version of Select2 are you using?

Comment: I am using select2.The version of Select2 is select2-3.4.5

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have three issues

1. You're using Select2 3.4.5, which was released in late 2013. There have been tons of bug fixes and improvements since then (and 4.0.0 is almost released), so getting support for it is going to be difficult in any channel.
2. You are using [the 4.0.0 documentation](https://select2.github.io/) instead of [the 3.5.2 documentation](http://select2.github.io/select2/). There are some changes that happened in 4.0.0 that explain why your code isn't fully working how you are expecting.

   1. You should be using `ajax.results` instead of `ajax.processResults`.  This explains why your method is never being called, it's not named correctly.
3. Your `ajax.transport` method isn't set up correctly. You are supposed to pass the results back through the `query.success` method (and errors through `query.error`) so Select2 can process them.

So, putting all of those together...

```
$(".users").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    multiple: true,
    ajax: {
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                'q': term
            };
        },                  
        results: function (data) {
            return { results: data };
        },
        transport: function(queryParams) {
            var params = {
                'term': queryParams.data.q
            };

            console.log(params);

            service.getUsersByQueru(params, function (data) { 
                queryParams.success(data);
            });
        }
    }    
});
```

Which should work as you are expecting, assuming that the `data` passed back from your service is formatted correctly.

Comment: It doesn't work....:(!!! When I call queryParams.success(data) I read in the console 'undefined' but if I do:console.log(queryParams) is not undefined.... I put in my question the service code too